# jqGrid dropdown has wrong value on edit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

One of the three dropdowns on my edit form is not being set correctly when the form opens.  The two other dropdowns on the form are properly set.  The dropdown data is being returned from the server in the form of `<select><option value='#'>blah</option></select>.`

classDesc, purchClass and company are three fields using a dropdown on the edit form.  All display correctly on the grid, but on the edit form company always displays the first option.  The value shown in the column on the grid is present in the dropdown data returned from the server but it's not being selected.  (See screenshot)  I've tried forcing the value in afterShowForm, but that has no effect.  jqGrid 4.6.0

Here's my column model:

```
colModel : [ 
    { name:'id', index:'id', width:50, sortable:true, hidden: false, editable: true, align: 'right', editrules: {edithidden: false}, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq','bw', 'cn']}, editrules: {required:true}},
    { name:'submittable', index:'submittable', width:42,sortable:false, align: 'center', search: false, cellattr: function () { return ' title="Submit this order"'; }},
    { name:'statusId', index:'statusId', width:50, sortable:false, hidden: true, editable: true, editrules: {edithidden: false}},
    { name:'statusClassId', index:'statusClassId', width:50, sortable:false, hidden: true, editable: true, editrules: {edithidden: false}},
    { name:'status', index:'status', width:100, sortable:true, hidden: false, editable:true, editoptions:{readonly:"true", defaultValue:"Open"}, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq','bw', 'cn']}, editrules: {required:true}},
    { name:'dlcd', index:'dlcd', width:50, sortable:true, hidden: false, editable:true, editoptions:{readonly: true, defaultValue:"<%=userDatabean.getNumber()%>"}, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq','bw', 'cn']}, editrules: {required:true}},
    { name:'classId', index:'classId', width:10, sortable:false, hidden: true, editable: true, editrules: {edithidden: false}},
    { name:'classDesc', index:'classDesc', width:75, sortable:true, editable:true, edittype:'select', editoptions: {dataUrl:'/rebate/rest/lookup/v1/getClass'}, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq','bw', 'cn']}, editrules: {required:true}},
    { name:'purchClassId', index:'purchClassId', width:10, sortable:false, hidden: true, editable: true, editrules: {edithidden: false}},
    { name:'purchClass', index:'purchClass', width:70, sortable:true, editable:true, edittype:'select', editoptions: { dataUrl:'/rebate/rest/lookup/v1/getPurch'}, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq','bw', 'cn']}, editrules: {required:true}},
    { name:'purchOther', index:'purchOther', width:150, sortable:false, hidden: true, editable:true, editrules: {edithidden: true}},
    { name:'custId', index:'custId', width:30, sortable:false, hidden: false, editable: true, editrules: {edithidden: false}},
    { name:'company', index:'company', width:175, sortable:true, editable:true, edittype:'select', editoptions: {dataUrl:'/rebate/rest/lookup/v1/getCustomer'}, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq','bw', 'cn']}, editrules: {required:true}},
    { name:'poNum', index:'poNum', width:15, sortable:false, hidden: true, editable:true, editrules: {edithidden: true}},
    { name:'deliveryDate', index:'deliveryDate', width:80, sortable:true, hidden: false, editable:true, sorttype: "integer", 
        formatter: function (cellValue, options, rowdata, action) {
            var date = new Date(cellValue);
            var year = date.getFullYear();
            var month = date.getMonth() < 9
                        ? "0" + (date.getMonth()+1)
                        : (date.getMonth()+1);
            var day = date.getDate() <=9
                        ? "0" + date.getDate()
                        : date.getDate();
            return [year,month,day].join("-");
         },
        searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq','bw', 'cn']}, editrules: {required:true},
        editoptions: {  maxlength: 12, dataInit: function(element){ $(element).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }) } }, 
        editrules: { date: true, required: false }, editrules: {required:true}},
    { name:'dlrInfo', index:'dlrInfo', width:15, sortable:false, hidden: true, editable:true, editrules: {edithidden: true}, editoptions:{size:50, maxlength: 100}},
    { name:'file1', index: 'file1', width:50, sortable:false, hidden: true, editable: true, editrules: {edithidden: true}},
    { name:'file2', index: 'file2', width:50, sortable:false, hidden: true, editable: true, editrules: {edithidden: true}},
    { name:'terms', index:'terms', width:50, sortable:false, hidden: true, editable: true, edittype:'checkbox', editoptions: {value:"true:false"}, editrules: {edithidden: true},
        formoptions:{label: '<a href="javascript:showTerms()">Terms</a>'}       
    },
],
```

And the navGrid w/the edit parameters:

```
    $("#orderGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#orderGridPager', {
    edit : true, 
    add : true, 
    del : false, 
    search : true

},{ //Edit form
    url : '/rebate/rest/header/v1/update',
    width: 600,
    viewPagerButtons: false,
    closeAfterEdit: true,
    recreateForm: true,
    modal: true,

    beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
        if($('#file1').val()=='') { //no file so add the file inputs
            $('#tr_file1').html('<td class="CaptionTD">Receipt 1</td><td class="DataTD">&nbsp;<input type="file" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="file1" name="file1" class="FormElement"></td>');
            $('#tr_file2').html('<td class="CaptionTD">Receipt 2</td><td class="DataTD">&nbsp;<input type="file" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="file2" name="file2" class="FormElement"></td>');

        } else { //we have a file so just show the file name
            $('#tr_file1').html('<td class="CaptionTD">Receipt 1</td><td class="CaptionTD">&nbsp;' + $('#file1').val() +'</td>');
            $('#tr_file2').html('<td class="CaptionTD">Receipt 2</td><td class="CaptionTD">&nbsp;' + $('#file2').val() +'</td>');
        }

        $form.find("#status,#dlcd,#id")
            .prop("readonly", true)
            .addClass("ui-state-disabled");

        if(!security[userLevel][$("#statusClassId").val()-1]) { 
            //make all fields read only.
            $form.find("input,select,button")
            .prop("disabled", true)
            .addClass("ui-state-disabled")
            .closest(".DataTD")
            .prev(".CaptionTD")
            .prop("disabled", true); 

            $form.parent().find('#sData').hide();   
        }
    },
    afterShowForm: function(formId) {
        $("#company").val($("#custId").val()).prop("select",true);

        console.log("after custId: " + $("#custId").val());
    },
    beforeSubmit: function(postdata, formid) {
        var chk = checkBeforeSubmit();
        if(!chk[0]) return chk;

        return [true, null, null];
    },
    serializeEditData: function (postdata) {
        return getFieldData("FrmGrid_orderGrid");
    },
    afterSubmit: function(response, postdata) {
        sendFormFiles(response.responseText);
        //console.log(response);
        $('#grid').trigger( 'reloadGrid' );
        return [true,null,null];
    },
    errorTextFormat: function(response) {
        return response.responseText=="" ?"400.1: An unknown error occured." : response.responseText;
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a data issue.

The query to populate the grid pulled in just the company name, the query for the lookup to build the dropdown was concatenating a few other fields into the display value.  I assumed jqgrid would use the custId value to select the right element in the dropdown but it's using the display value.